# visual studio code setting to display only the leading part of the file and not the full file name

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual studio code, opening files results in display of the full file name in the file editor tab, resulting in occupying the entire tab header space with only a few tabs when file names are long Ex.MyFancyComp.component.ts. Newly opened files show up by hiding older un-editted files.

This results in re-opening the previously opened files with ctrl-P command every now and then.

Is there any setting in vscode to minimize the tab size so as to accommodate more opened files within the editor?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Found it.
Preferences->Settings->Workbench->Editor Management->Tab Sizing: Change value from fit to shrink.

You would prefer having 'Tab close button' set to left.

Thanks